# diagonal in a 4x4 matrix comparison

Tags: java

Trying to figure out how to compare if all the elements on the secondary diagonal of a 4x4 matrix are all equal to each other. how could i go about doing this? 
how about for the main diagonal

the matrix looks something like this

```
00 01 02 03
10 11 12 13
20 21 22 23
30 31 32 33
```

i am asking because i am trying to implement a resizable board tic tac toe game in java. i have already did 3x3 board and it works just fine but i now want to make it 4x4 and hopefully n x n, but have no clue as to how to implement the endGame() method for arrays greater than 3x3.

ideas would be greatly apreciated

sample endGame() for 3x3 :

```
     /*horizontal game end, dr and dc are just a row and column that is kept constant while changing the second parameter for comparison*/
     if(gameBoard[dr][0] == gameBoard[dr][2] && gameBoard[dr][0] == gameBoard[dr][1]) return true;

     /*check for vertical game end*/

     if(gameBoard[0][dc] == gameBoard[1][dc] && gameBoard[0][dc] == gameBoard[2][dc]) return true;

     /*check for diagonal game end*/

     if(gameBoard[0][2] == gameBoard[1][1] && gameBoard[0][2] == gameBoard[2][0] && gameBoard[0][2]!='_') return true;
     if(gameBoard[0][0] == gameBoard[1][1] && gameBoard[0][0] == gameBoard[2][2] && gameBoard[0][0]!='_') return true;
     return false;
 }
```

Comment: Java is [**not** the same thing](http://javascriptisnotjava.io/) as JavaScript. This looks like Java**Script**. Please remember to tag correctly; I've corrected this for you. In future, please remember to only tag the **relevant** coding language(s). For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge How can you tell? The included code is valid in both Java and JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit confusing. I'm really not sure any more.

Comment: @Adrian Before trying to do anything, you should define formally (mathematically) what an "end game" state is for an `n` x `n` matrix. With that formal definition in place, it should be simple to start programming it in.